# What does the ghdl compile vhdl to?

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

Does ghdl compile vhdl code into a virtual circuit implemented gate by gate? If that can I see the circuit it compiled?

Comment: GHDL's documentation answers that : No. If you're using the LLVM or GCC versions, it compiles down to an executable that runs natively on your computer. (the Mcode version is different : it's a JIT compiler that doesn't generate a standalone executable). To get a virtual circuit, you need a synthesis tool, not a simulator.

Comment: GHDL is a simulator. What you are looking for is logic synthesis. Look at Synopsis, Xilinx Vivado, Intel/Altera Quartus, etc.

Comment: GHDL has an experimental mode to emit a netlist (synthesized design, but not optimized and not mapped) for the IceStorm synthesis tool chain targeting the Lattice iCE devices.